# Python Django ListView not calling get_queryset

Tags: django, python-3.x

Our group is trying to use the listview class to display all of the posts in a list format to the user in a news feed style. We created the `ListView` class with a valid `template_name` and `context_object_name`. Then, we implemented the get queryset to retrieve all of the posts from the db (`all()` method):

```
class PostsView(generic.ListView):
  template_name = 'home.html'
  context_object_name = 'all_posts_list'

  def get_queryset(self):
    return Post.objects.all()
```

However, this `get_queryset` method is not being run when we call the view. When I have built other apps in the past, the get_queryset was called automatically for my `ListView` objects, as it should according to the [ListView documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/). Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This should indeed run. How do you know that this `get_queryset` is not performed? What if you add a `print(..)` statement *before* the `return`?

Comment: Also, check your `urls.py` so that the endpoint maps to that view correctly.

Comment: Yes I have tried print statements before the return in the get_queryset method. The html is displayed correctly at the endpoint, it just doesn't retrieve any list because the get_queryset is not being called

Comment: What if you try and add `queryset = Post.objects.all()` as a class attribute, instead of using the `get_queryset` method?

Answer (score 1):

Have you overridden def `get(self, request,*args,**kwargs)` method in your list view?If yes , you need to call `super().get(*args,**kwargs)`; this will call `get_queryset()`